# Userfrosting: How to make user login automatically soon after registration

Tags: userfrosting

In our usecase, we need to login the user automatically soon after successful registration for enabling, rather forcing the user to:

1. Change password.
2. Upload a file.

How to achieve this programmatically, in AccountController's register method?

Ideally, it should be a seamless registration process that ends with the login state in the user dashboard.

Request valuable help / hint / pointers...

Thanks!

Comment: For your use case, do you require users to verify their accounts via a verification email?

Comment: @alexw Thanks Alex, ideally users need to verify their accounts, but since we are not able to get the file upload thing as a part of registration process, but have it working in the dashboard, we want them to login seamlessly as a part of registration process, upload their file etc. So no need of verification as of now. They will be verified manually by admin team.

Comment: So what you want is for them to be automatically logged in after registration?

Comment: @alexw Yes! and take them to specific option (route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is to take a cue from the [password reset controller](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/controllers/AccountController.php#L645-L656), which already does this (in this case, it automatically logs the user in after they've selected a new password).

So, add this to the bottom of the `register` method in `AccountController`:

```
// Log out any existing user, and create a new session
if (!$this->_app->user->isGuest()) {
    $this->_app->logout(true);
    // Restart session
    $this->_app->startSession();
}
// Auto-login the user
$this->_app->login($user);
$ms = $this->_app->alerts;
$ms->addMessageTranslated("success", "ACCOUNT_WELCOME", $this->_app->user->export());
```

You will also need to modify the [AJAX callback in `register.twig`](https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/templates/themes/default/account/register.twig#L151-L152) to redirect the user to the home page, instead of the login page:

```
window.location.replace(site['uri']['public']);
```

The user will then be automatically redirected to the landing page for their primary group after being logged in.